# Simple z-transformation over all columns

Tags: r, transformation, sapply

I just wrote a very basic function for the z tranformation in a Matrix over all columns. It looks like this:

`sapply(MyObject, function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)})`

I randomly checked my function for some cells within the Matrix and it seems to work fine. Still I wanted to confirm the function is okay, because I'm very new to R and I could not find any good examples on the internet.

Comment: You might want to look at `scale()`:-) (BTW, if there are missing values, your function will fail: you need to add `na.rm=TRUE` when you call `mean` and `sd`.)

Comment: I knew there was a function already there :) But it's weired thoug because when I apply scale funktion like this: `sapply(MyObject, function(x){scale(x)})` I get totally diffrent values...might it be that he is executing the scale transformation with the mean and SD from the whole Matrix?

Comment: You don't need `sapply()` to apply `scale()`. Just do `scale(MyObject)`. You should get the same results then (well similar, they'll both be matrices but the `scale()` result will have attributes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at `scale()` which does this for you.

Your function is close to being correct; you should add `na.rm = TRUE` to both the `sd()` and `mean()` function calls.

I would write (if not using `scale()`) the function using `sweep()` instead of the `sapply()`. E.g.

```
ztran <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
    mns <- colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    sds <- apply(x, 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm)
    x <- sweep(x, 2, mns, "-")
    x <- sweep(x, 2, sds, "/")
    x
}
```

In use we have

```
> df <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3))
> ztran(df)
  X1 X2 X3
1 -1 -1 -1
2  0  0  0
3  1  1  1
> scale(df)
     X1 X2 X3
[1,] -1 -1 -1
[2,]  0  0  0
[3,]  1  1  1
attr(,"scaled:center")
X1 X2 X3 
 2  5  8 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
X1 X2 X3 
 1  1  1
```

`sweep` is a very useful vectorised tool for this sort of operation. Notice also that `sapply()` simplifies to a matrix, which may not be what you wanted. `sweep()` doesn't do this:

```
> class(ztran(df))
[1] "data.frame"
> class(sapply(df, function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}))
[1] "matrix"
```

Comment: ok. I got this working. But I'm not sure if I unterstood very well the advantage of `sweep`. Is it that sweep allows me to execute the function seperated for choosen columns and sapply automatically works the whole matrix?

Comment: Nope, `sweep()` works on all columns (`2`) [or rows (change `2` to `1`)]. The advantage is that i) `sweep()` is vectorised, the `sapply()` solution isn't, it just hides the loop; `sapply()` doesn't play that nicely with data frames, as witnessed by it simplifying to a matrix. Both allow you to choose which columns are worked on: `sweep(df[, c(1,3)], ....)` or `sapply(df[, c(1,3)], ....)`.